# Enable Dialogflow API on Google Cloud Project using Service Accounts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to create new Agents in different projects using Service Accounts (I don't know any alternative to Service Accounts) but as I suspect because Service Accounts are specific to a project, I cannot enable the corresponding Dialogflow API using any kind of REST API or something alike. Any help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Beside using the Cloud console, you can enable Cloud APIs using [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/services/enable) and [Service Usage API](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/reference/rest/v1/services/enable)

Using Gcloud command:

gcloud services enable dialogflow.googleapis.com

Using RESTful API services.enable method:

POST https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1/projects/12345678901/services/dialogflow.googleapis.com:enable

The used service account requires serviceusage.services.enable that you can include in a [custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles) and assign it to the used service account.

The following is the link for the console method:
https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?project=[YOUR_PROJECT]&apiid=dialogflow.googleapis.com